# How can I decide the bitmap size should a android widget use

Tags: android, bitmap, widget

I'm now trying writing a resizable android widget for Android 4.4.

It works fine in Android Studio's emulator and my Sony Xperia Z2 mobile phone. But it goes wrong in my friend's **Huawei mobile phone. The image is in very low resolution** and looks terrible.

The **widget contains only a ImageView** and I'll make a bitmap set into it when doing update.

I want to know **what size of the bitmap should be**. After searching the Internet I'm trying getting the size of widget through

```
 Bundle widgetOpts = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(widgetId);
 int dpwidth = widgetOpts.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH);
 int dpheight = widgetOpts.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT);
```

and compute the size of bitmap by multiple it with density

```
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = (int)(dpwidth * dm.density);
int height = (int)(dpheight * dm.density);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
```

The value is like this in her Huawei mobile phone for a 2x1 widget:

```
OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH 74
OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT 34
Density 2.0
DensityDpi 320
ScaledDensity 2.0
xdpi 315.31
ydpi 315.65
screen width 720
screen height 1184
```

and the values in Sony Xperia Z2 is like this

```
OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH 225
OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT 97
Density 3.0
DensityDpi 480
ScaledDensity 3.0
xdpi 428.625
ydpi 427.789
screen width 1080
screen height 1776
```

In Sony Xperia Z2, the dpwidth * density = 675px, is over the half of screen width (in home screen, a 2x1 widget's width should be less then half of the screen I think); in Huawei, the dpwidth * density = 148px, is less than a quarter of the screen's width. **Neither of them** looks like the widget's width in pixel.

Are there any advices?

In Sony Xperia Z2:
[image: my widget in sony xperia z2]

In Huawei:
[image: my widget in huawei]